# How do I appropriately handle field change events in React using a custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am currently building a simple signup form page to build my knowledge of React Web Apps. I have a number of different types of form elements. I am running into the following error when I use my custom hook to handle changes in any of the form fields that are not simple text fields.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/paris/Desktop/covidsocial/frontend/src/libs/hooksLib.js:11
function(event) {

```
  9 |     setValues({
  10 |       ...fields,
> 11 |       [event.target.name]: event.target.value
     | ^  12 |     });
  13 |   }
  14 | ];
```

The above error message occurs anytime i select a country from the region and country selector drop-downs or the date picker. I have tried using both name and control-id elements as the ids but I still get the same error message as above. I think the issue is with how I am setting my values, but I am very new to React and am having trouble pinning down exactly whats going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Here is the relevant code for my Signup.js class as well as the custom react hook

**hookslib.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
export function useFormFields(initialState) {
  const [fields, setValues] = useState(initialState);
  return [
    fields,
    function(event) {
      setValues({
        ...fields,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      });
    }
  ];
}
```

**Signup.js**

```
export default function Signup() {
  const [fields, handleFieldChange] = useFormFields({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
    confirmationCode: "",
    gender: "",
    onList: false,
    dateOfBirth: "",
    mailingAddressLine1: "",
    mailingAddressLine2: "",
    mailingAddressCity: "",
    mailingAddressState: "",
    mailingAddressZip: "",
    billingAddressLine1: "",
    billingAddressLine2: "",
    billingAddressCity: "",
    billingAddressState: "",
    billingAddressZip: "",
    useShippingAsBilling: false,

  });
  const history = useHistory();
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState(null);
  const { userHasAuthenticated } = useAppContext();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  function validateForm() {
    return (
      fields.email.length > 0 &&
      fields.password.length > 0 &&
      fields.password === fields.confirmPassword
    );
  }

  function validateConfirmationForm() {
    return fields.confirmationCode.length > 0;
  }

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const newUser = await Auth.signUp({
        username: fields.email,
        password: fields.password,
        confirmPassword: fields.confirmPassword,
        gender: fields.gender,
        firstName: fields.firstName,
        lastName: fields.lastName,
        onList: fields.onList,
        dateOfBirth: fields.dateOfBirth,
        mailingAddressLine1: fields.mailingAddressLine1,
        mailingAddressLine2: fields.mailingAddressLine2,
        mailingAddressCity: fields.mailingAddressCity,
        mailingAddressState: fields.mailingAddressState,
        mailingAddressZip: fields.mailingAddressZip,
        mailingAddressCountry: fields.mailingAddressCountry,
        billingAddressCountry: fields.billingAddressCountry,
        billingAddressLine1: fields.billingAddressLine1,
        billingAddressLine2: fields.billingAddressLine2,
        billingAddressCity: fields.billingAddressCity,
        billingAddressState: fields.billingAddressState,
        billingAddressZip: fields.billingAddressZip,
      });
      setIsLoading(false);
      setNewUser(newUser);
    } catch (e) {
      onError(e);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  async function handleConfirmationSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      await Auth.confirmSignUp(fields.email, fields.confirmationCode);
      await Auth.signIn(fields.email, fields.password);

      userHasAuthenticated(true);
      history.push("/");
    } catch (e) {
      onError(e);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  function renderConfirmationForm() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleConfirmationSubmit}>
        <FormGroup controlId="confirmationCode" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Confirmation Code</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            autoFocus
            type="tel"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.confirmationCode}
          />
          <HelpBlock>Please check your email for the code.</HelpBlock>
        </FormGroup>

        <LoaderButton
          block
          type="submit"
          bsSize="large"
          isLoading={isLoading}
          disabled={!validateConfirmationForm()}
        >
          Verify
        </LoaderButton>
      </form>
    );
  }

  function renderForm() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormGroup controlId="email" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            autoFocus
            name = "email"
            type="email"
            value={fields.email}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="password" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="password"
            name = "password"
            value={fields.password}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="confirmPassword" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Confirm Password</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="password"
            name = "confirmPassword"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.confirmPassword}
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="mailingAddressLine1" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Mailing Address Line 1</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name = "mailingAddressLine1"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.mailingAddressLine1}
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="mailingAddressLine2" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Mailing Address Line 2</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name = "mailingAddressLine2"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.mailingAddressLine2}
          />
        </FormGroup>


        <FormGroup controlId="mailingAddressCountry" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Country</ControlLabel>
          <CountryDropdown
            name = "mailingAddressCountry"
            country={fields.mailingAddressCountry}
            value={fields.mailingAddressCountry}
            onChange={handleFieldChange} />
        </FormGroup>


        <FormGroup controlId="mailingAddressRegion" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>State</ControlLabel>
          <RegionDropdown
            //country={country}
            name="mailingAddressRegion"
            country={fields.mailingAddressCountry}
            value={fields.mailingAddressState}
            onChange={handleFieldChange} />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="city" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>City</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name="city"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.mailingAddressCity}
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="zipCode" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Zip Code</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name="zipCode"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.mailingAddressZip}
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="useShippingAsBilling" bsSize="large">
          <label>
            Use Shipping As Billing:
          <input
              name = "useShippingAsBilling"
              type="checkbox"
              id="useShippingasBilling"
              value={fields.useShippingAsBilling}
              checked={fields.useShippingAsBilling === true}
              onChange={handleFieldChange} />
          </label>
        </FormGroup>
        <br />


        <FormGroup controlId="billingAddressLine1" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Billing Address Line 1</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            name ="billingAddressLine1"
            type="text"
            value={fields.billingAddressLine1}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="billingAddressLine2" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Billing Address Line 2</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
           name ="billingAddressLine2"
            type="text"
            value={fields.billingAddressLine2}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>


        <FormGroup controlId="billingAddressCountry" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>BillingAddressCountry</ControlLabel>
          <CountryDropdown
             name="billingAddressCountry"
            value={fields.billingAddressCountry}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>


        <FormGroup controlId="mailingAddressRegion" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Billing Address Region</ControlLabel>
          <RegionDropdown
          name="mailingAddressRegion"
            country={fields.billingAddressCountry}
            value={fields.billingAddressRegion}
            onChange={handleFieldChange} />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="billingCity" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>City</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            name = "billingCity"
            type="text"
            value={fields.billingAddressCity}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="billingZipCode" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Zip Code</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            name = "billingZipCode"
            type="text"
            value={fields.billingAddressZip}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="gender" bsSize="sm">
          <ControlLabel>Gender</ControlLabel>
          <br></br>
          <ControlLabel>Male</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
           name = "gender"
            type="radio"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.gender}
            checked={fields.gender === 'male'}
          />
          <ControlLabel>Female</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
          name = "gender"
            type="radio"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.gender}
            checked={fields.gender === 'female'}
          />
          <ControlLabel>Other</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
          name = "gender"
            type="radio"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.gender}
            checked={fields.gender === 'other'}
          />
        </FormGroup>


        <FormGroup controlId="onList" bsSize="sm">
          <br></br>
          <ControlLabel>Join Email List</ControlLabel>
          <br></br>
          <ControlLabel>Yes</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
          name = "onList"
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            value={fields.onList}
            checked={fields.onList === 'true'}
          />
        </FormGroup>


        <FormGroup controlId="dateOfBirth">
        <ControlLabel>Date of Birth</ControlLabel>
          <DatePicker
           name="dateOfBirth"
            value={fields.dateofBirth}
            selected={fields.dateOfBirth}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
            locale="en"
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup controlId="content">
          <ControlLabel>Notes Area</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            name = "content"
            value={fields.content}
            componentClass="textarea"
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <LoaderButton
          block
          type="submit"
          bsSize="large"
          isLoading={isLoading}
          disabled={!validateForm()}
        >
          Signup
        </LoaderButton>
      </form>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="Signup">
      {newUser === null ? renderForm() : renderConfirmationForm()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clever approach to handling change events and persisting values to state. You do, however, put a lot of faith in this component library to fire onChange events consistently with their HTML counterparts.

I noticed in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-country-region-selector) that the onChange is a little different than you might expect:

```
<CountryDropdown
    value={country}
    onChange={(val) => this.selectCountry(val)} />
<RegionDropdown
    country={country}
    value={region}
    onChange={(val) => this.selectRegion(val)} />
```

Both of these expect an arrow function handler to receive the val property, so you might consider rewriting your implementation:

```
<CountryDropdown
    name = "mailingAddressCountry"
    country={fields.mailingAddressCountry}
    value={fields.mailingAddressCountry}
    onChange={(val) => updateField({ mailingAddress: val})} />
```

And modify your hook to so that you aren't working from the bare event. It'll require a little more syntax, and there's probably a cleaner way to approach, but it will give you the control you need to handle edge cases. Something like so:

```
import { useState } from "react";
export function useFormFields(initialState) {
  const [fields, setValues] = useState(initialState);
  return [
    fields,
    function(value) {
      setValues({
        ...fields,
        ...value
      });
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Can you elaborate more on what you mean by modifying the hook so that its not working from the bare event?

Comment: I modified my original answer to show how you could approach the hook. If you call updateField with an object (e.g. { mailingAddress: val}) then you can use the spread operator to add/override values in fields object from within your hook. Note how the hook is no longer dependent on the event.

Comment: So i changed my fields to be objects like this billingAddress: {
      billingAddressLine1: "",
      billingAddressLine2: "",
      billingAddressCity: "",
      billingAddressCountry: "",
      billingAddressState: "",
      billingAddressZip: "",
    },                                                                                                                               Is this the correct way to access the values inside my form fields?             
   value={fields.billingAddress['billingAddressCountry']}